# Unexpectedly found nil but print shows valid string

Tags: swift

I am trying to set an Image and two label texts like this:

```
cell.ogImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.ogImageURL))
cell.titleLabel.text = post.title
cell.urlLabel.text = post.url
```

If I print out the strings just before that:

```
print(post.ogImageURL)
print(post.title)
print(post.url)
```

I am getting a valid strings, along with the error:

[image]

Commenting out the `sd_setImage...` also gives the same error for the `title` and the `url`.

**Question**: What's going on here? Since the string is fine, I guess `URL` is the one returning nil here? But why I am also getting errors for title and url, eventhough they are all fine?

The class for the Cell:

```
class LinksCell: MGSwipeTableCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var urlLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ogImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

The `viewDidLoad()` where I populate them:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
linksTableView.register(LinksCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "linksCellident")

        dataSource = FUITableViewDataSource.init(query: getQuery()) { (tableView, indexPath, snap) -> MGSwipeTableCell in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "linksCellident", for: indexPath) as! LinksCell

            guard let post = LinksPost.init(snapshot: snap) else { return cell }
            print(post.ogImageURL)
            print(post.title)
            print(post.url)
            cell.ogImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.ogImageURL))
            cell.titleLabel.text = post.title
            cell.urlLabel.text = post.url

            return cell
    }
    dataSource?.bind(to: linksTableView)
    linksTableView.delegate = self
}
```

The "LinksPost" class:

```
class LinksPost: NSObject {

    var url: String
    var title: String
    var ogImageURL: String

    init(url: String, title: String, ogImageURL: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.ogImageURL = ogImageURL
    }

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else { return nil }
        guard let url  = dict["url"]  else { return nil }
        guard let title = dict["ogTitle"] else { return nil }
        guard let ogImageURL = dict["ogImageURL"] else { return nil }

        print(ogImageURL)
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.ogImageURL = ogImageURL
    }

    convenience override init() {
        self.init(url: "", title: "", ogImageURL: "")
    }
}
```

Debugging the Variables also shows valid strings:

[image]

Debugging the contents of `cell`:
[image]

Comment: Seems like there is nothing at this URL, just try to put URL into browser

Comment: There is though. Commenting out the Image part also gives `nil` for the two label texts.

Comment: if all strings are valid one (or both) of the labels might be not connected properly. Set a breakpoint and find out.

Comment: Are you using static or dynamic cells?  If static, delete you outlets and reset them.

Comment: In which line are you getting this error?

Comment: @FangmingNing for all of the `cell...` lines in the very first code snippet above.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Redid all of the outlets. No change.

Comment: Can you show where `cell` came from? (Where's your `cell = ...` line?)

Comment: @smarx Updated the question.

Comment: Should `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` be `linksTableView.dequeueReusableCell`? (Or perhaps `linksTableView.register` should be `tableView.register`?)

Comment: @vadian I am following the Firebase quickstart guide, they provide a library with bindings, I thought this was OK: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/database/DatabaseExampleSwift/PostListViewController.swift

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with FireBase. It looks very complicated – pretty much more complicated than the traditional data source workflow.

Comment: @vadian Sure is. Honestly so done with this, haven't gotten a single stable build working where no exception is thrown at some point.

Comment: `cell.ogImageView`, `cell.titleLabel` or `cell.urlLabel` can be nil. Have you checked the contents of `cell` with debugger?

Comment: @OOPer Updated above. Seems fine.

Comment: @ffritz Did you see my comment? It seems like you're registering the cell on one table view and then dequeuing it on a different one.

Comment: @smarx `tableView` is just the local variable within the `FUITableViewDataSource.init` function, or not? At the end of the `viewDidLoad()` I am binding them.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the function there.

Comment: Maybe `linksTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LinksCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "linksCellident")`?

Comment: @smarx Had that initally, I do not have a xib file though, I am using storyboard. This gives a nib bundle error.

Comment: Your screen shot does not have enough info about if `cell` is fine or not. What do you get if you put `print(cell.ogImageView, cell.titleLabel, cell.urlLabel)` after `print(post.url)` ?

Comment: Any chance you can share a full runnable project?

Comment: @smarx Ofc. Check your Mail.

Comment: Seems like there's a missing `Podfile`?

Comment: @smarx I see, added.

Comment: @ffritz See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to work if you delete this line:

```
linksTableView.register(...)
```

I'm *very* unfamiliar with iOS development, so take this with a grain of salt. (Perhaps experts can chime in?) I think the issue is that this is already set up via your prototype content in your storyboard, and registering here again basically undoes the outlets that are set up. You're ending up with `nil` values for the `ogImageView`, `titleLabel`, and `urlLabel`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Great insights. Seems like when using prototype cells there this registering needs to be implemented differently.

Comment: @ffritz Assuming this took care of it, can you accept this answer so others don't keep trying? :-)

Comment: will do asap. Need to verify one more thing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure but is your tableView.dataSource linked up correctly? Is your cell nil? Try breakpointing after each step in the callback for your FUITableViewDataSource and see what line is causing the crash.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, and besides, the question has already been answered.